# Reagent atom swap! change state to all values from keys

Tags: clojure, reagent

We have an atom with some keys and boolean values:

```
(def btns (reagent.core/atom {:a true :b true :c true}))
```

I need to change the state of all keys, like this: `{:a false :b false :c false}`

I tried this, but not good solution, and not working:

```
   (for [btn @btns]
        (swap! btns assoc (key btn) false))
```

Comment: This one is lazy, if you replace ror with doseq it should work. But that is still not the 'clojure' way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can update multiple keys this way:

```
user> (def a (atom {:a true :b true :c true}))
;;=> #<Atom@af0fa6a: {:a true, :b true, :c true}>

user> (swap! a into {:b false :c false})
;;=> {:a true, :b false, :c false}
```

or like this:

```
user> (swap! a assoc :a false :c false)
;;=> {:a false, :b true, :c false}
```

if you want to update all the keys in atom to false it could also look like this:

```
user> (reset! a (zipmap (keys @a) (repeat false)))
;;=> {:a false, :b false, :c false}
```

or like this:

```
user> (swap! a #(zipmap (keys %) (repeat false)))
;;=> {:a false, :b false, :c false}
```

**update**

also, it is good to abstract out the util function, to make it more readable:

```
(defn assoc-all-keys [data val]
  (zipmap (keys data) (repeat val)))

user> (swap! a assoc-all-keys false)
;;=> {:a false, :b false, :c false}
```